# WinSCP .NET assemblies - Timeout for Session.GetFiles to throw an exception

Tags: c#, exception, timeout, winscp, winscp-net

I wrote a class that is using C# WinSCP .NET assembly.

The class is saving a WinSCP `Session` as a field, and when I call function "Start" the class initializes a WinSCP `Session` and opens it, and then repeatedly calls `Session.GetFiles` every 2 seconds.

I want to handle every exception case in my class, and there is one case I can't get an exception.

The case is : I run my class, it connects to the FTP server and starts repeatedly looking for files to download (listing which is happening in `Session.GetFiles`). After a few times it calls `GetFiles` I shut down the FTP server.  The next time `GetFiles` is called, the program gets stuck on a blocking method (`GetFiles`) which is waiting for the server to be up again. Only after 1.5-2 minutes it throws a `SessionRemoteException` with the message: *"No connection could be made because the target machine  actively refused it"*.

I want this to be thrown after 10 seconds of blocking and not random 1.5-2 minutes.

I tried using every Timeout method that is mentioned in WinSCP website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`Session.ReconnectTime`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#reconnecttime). It defaults to 120 seconds.

```
session.ReconnectTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```